# Regex for this double handlebar pattern not working in the following case

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-look-ahead

I have created regex pattern for this: {{}}-{{}}-{{}}

`(?<![^*])(^|[^{])\{\{[^{}]*\}\}(?!\})([-]{1}\{\{[^{}]*\}\}(?!\})){2}(?![^*])`

Double handle bars repeated exactly 3 times with dashes in between.

But the regex pattern is failing for the following case:

`-{{}}-{{}}-{{}}`

i.e., the pattern is matching even though a dash(-) is present before the first double handlebars. It ideally shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part `(?<![^*])` means that these should not be a char other than `*` directly to the left of the current position (which is also used in the negative lookahead at the end of the pattern)

Instead you can assert a whitspace boundary to the left and to the right.

Note that this part `[-]{1}` can be written as just `-`

```
(?<!\S)\{\{[^{}]*\}\}(?:-\{\{[^{}]*\}\}){2}(?!\S)
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/UagaSR/1).

Comment: this pattern now fails: abcd{{}}-{{}}-{{}}abcd. The regex evaluator is not marking it as fail. The requirement being that no characters should be present to the left of the first double handlebars and to the right of 3rd double handle bars.

Comment: @vrn Then you can write it as `(?<!\S)\{\{[^{}]*\}\}(?:-\{\{[^{}]*\}\}){2}(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/UagaSR/1

Comment: The expression matches even if space is present in the beginning and the end. So I made a slight modification to the above pattern ```(?<![\S\s])\{\{[^{}]*\}\}(?:-\{\{[^{}]*\}\}){2}(?![\S\s])```. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @vrn In that case you can also anchor the pattern `^\{\{[^{}]*\}\}(?:-\{\{[^{}]*\}\}){2}$`